# Prevent including the same file during nested include

Tags: php, include

Assume the following files:

a.php
b.php
c.php

a.php includes c.php
b.php includes c.php
a.php includes b.php

This makes a.php include c.php twice.
Is there any way to remove this conflict?

Comment: think of a better designed application

Comment: Read the documentation.  `include_once()`. http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php

Comment: thank you @Michael that is what I was searching.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The **include_once()** statement includes and evaluates the specified file during the execution of the script. This is a behavior similar to the include() statement, with the only difference being that if the code from a file has already been included, it will not be included again. As the name suggests, it will be included just once.

Ref: [include_once()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php)

Answer (score 2):

use `include_once()` instead of `include()`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `include_once()` (see [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php)) or `require_once()` (see [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php)) if you need/want to do the inclusion manually or may an autoloader would be a better way then including them "manually" (see [here](http://php.net/manual/de/function.spl-autoload-register.php)).